# Why a Many2one field related to X model is showing options of Y model?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have the following field in my customized model, named `accounting_heads.elementary_head`:

```
sub_heads = fields.Many2one('accounting_heads.sub_heads',domain = "[('heads', '=', heads)]", string= 'Sub Heads')
```

Despite having a *Many2one* relation with the `accounting_heads.sub_heads` 
model, it is showing records of `accounting_heads.accounting_heads` model.

Why?

Here are my models:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class accounting_heads(models.Model):
    _name = 'accounting_heads.accounting_heads'
    _rec_name = 'heads'

    heads = fields.Char()


class sub_heads(models.Model):
    _name = 'accounting_heads.sub_heads'
    _inherit = 'accounting_heads.accounting_heads'

    heads = fields.Many2one('accounting_heads.accounting_heads', string= 'Heads')
    sub_heads= fields.Char(string ='Sub Heads')


class elementary_heads(models.Model):
    _name = 'accounting_heads.elementary_head'

    _inherits = {'accounting_heads.accounting_heads': 'heads',
     'accounting_heads.sub_heads' : 'sub_heads',
     }

    heads = fields.Many2one('accounting_heads.accounting_heads', string='Heads')
    sub_heads = fields.Many2one('accounting_heads.sub_heads',domain = "[('heads', '=', heads)]", string= 'Sub Heads')
    elementary_heads = fields.Char(string = 'Elementary Head')
```

And here is my view:

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="accounting_heads.elementary_form">
      <field name="name">Form</field>
      <field name="model">accounting_heads.elementary_head</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form >
          <field name="heads" string="Head"/>
          <field name="sub_heads" string="Sub Head"/>
          <field name="elementary_heads" string="Elementary Head"/>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you do not have any field `name` created in `sub_heads` model, so the display name of the Many2one field `sub_heads` is taking the value of `heads` field by default.

Try to add the following code inside your `accounting_heads.sub_heads` model/class:

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for sub_head in self:
        result.append((sub_head.id, sub_head.display_name))
    return result

@api.multi
@api.depends('sub_heads')
def _compute_display_name(self):
    for sub_head in self:
        sub_head.display_name = sub_head.sub_heads
```

Other faster option is to add to the same model/class just the following line:

```
_rec_name = 'sub_heads'
```

Comment: Thanks . That's Work like charm.